# Eclipse SWT: How to unmask style combination from getStyle()

Tags: java, swt

This is for standard Eclipse SWT (in RCP). Suppose I have a shell

```
Shell shell = new Shell(parent);
```

I can get the style value from method shell.getStyle(). Let's say its 33555696. Then how can I get the actual style combination for this value? That is, how can I retrieve the original style definition SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE ...?

I got some help from this blog http://blog.vogella.com/2011/01/25/swt-style-bits/ It tells how to check for a specific style but still I don't know how to get the combination. Thanks

Comment: As Style Bits are all about powers of 2, it is probably more useful representing the value in hex, in this case `33555696 == 0x20004F0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bitwise-OR value is not an `EnumSet`. It doesn't contain the style constants themselves. It just contains the *values* of the constants, combined with bitwise-OR.

In addition, multiple style constants have the same value. Different constants are appropriate in different contexts. For example, the value `1<<4` is used for the style constants `SWT.RADIO`, `SWT.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN`, `SWT.RESIZE`, `SWT.NO_SCROLL`, `SWT.PHONETIC` and `SWT.ICON_WORKING`.

For a particular context, you could test each of its legal style constants one-by-one. From that, you could generate code that would produce the value.

Answer (score 2):

The SWTSpy tool is your friend here, it will tell you what the style bits are in words, see below for Demo and Install instructions.

However, for your specific question, you probably want the source of SWTSpy that converts style bits to a string. @AndyThomas is correct that for every type of control the style bits may have a different meaning. That is why SWTSpy has a huge if/else chain to resolve it for you.

Here is a sample:

```
if ((style & 1 << 3) != 0) {
        if (w instanceof Menu) {
                result += "POP_UP | ";
        } else if (w instanceof Button || w instanceof MenuItem || w instanceof ToolItem) {
                result += "PUSH | ";
        } else if (w instanceof Combo || w instanceof Text || w instanceof StyledText) {
                result += "READ_ONLY | ";
        } else if (w instanceof Label || w instanceof Group || w instanceof ToolBar) {
                result += "SHADOW_OUT | ";
        } else if (w instanceof Decorations) {
                result += "NO_TRIM | "; 
        } else {
                result += "POP_UP or PUSH or READ_ONLY or SHADOW_OUT or NO_TRIM or NATIVE | ";
        }
}
```

You could incorporate [that code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.swt.tools/src/org/eclipse/swt/tools/views/SpyView.java#n212) into your code if needed.

### Using SWT Spy

Once you have installed the SWT Spy (See below):

1. Open the view (`Window` -> `Show View` -> `Other` -> `SWT Spy`)
2. Turn on the spy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or press the button in the top of the view.
3. Hover over the control of interest
4. Examine all its properties, including the style bits
5. To "freeze" the spy so it stops tracking the mouse, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> again.

Here is a screenshot, showing that the highlighted Add button has Style: `PUSH | FLAT | CENTER | LEFT_TO_RIGHT | DOUBLE_BUFFERED`

[image: swtspy]

### Install

How to install SWTSpy (part of SWT Tools):

1. From `Help` -> `Install New Software`
2. Choose `The Eclipse Project Updates`
3. Type `swt tools` in the filter box (as seen in screenshot below)
4. Complete the wizard

[image: swttools]

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful information and explanation